WPF SharedSizeGroup Columns Not Rendering Correctly
I'm facing an issue with SharedSizeGroup for columns in WPF Grids not rendering correctly in my WPF application. The Grid is contained in a FlowDocument and when I try to convert the FlowDocument to a FixedDocument, a Visual is rendered that contains the Grid with SharedSizeGroup columns. When generating the fixed document or also saving the visual to an image, the shared columns are not correctly sized, leading to an incorrect layout in the rendered output.
Here is the code I am using:

Private Sub RenderPageContent(container As ContainerVisual, originalPage As DocumentPage)
    ' Render the Visual to a DrawingVisual
    Dim pageVisual As New DrawingVisual()
    Using ctx As DrawingContext = pageVisual.RenderOpen()
        ctx.DrawRectangle(New VisualBrush(originalPage.Visual), Nothing, New Rect(New Point(), originalPage.Size))
    End Using

    ' Add the rendered visual to the container
    container.Children.Add(pageVisual)
End Sub

However, this approach doesn't seem to properly handle the SharedSizeGroup columns. The columns are autosized for each Grid individually. How can render the columns correctly? The results in a DocumentViewer are correct. But the FixedDocument is wrong.
Strangely, it renders correctly on some Computers and not on others!??

The problem is due to how WPF's layout system handles SharedSizeGroup. This feature relies on a full layout pass to correctly calculate and apply the shared column widths across multiple Grid elements. When rendering a Visual off-screen outside the regular UI flow, the necessary layout passes might not occur, causing the shared columns to be incorrectly sized.
To fix this issue, a layout pass has to be forced by temporarily hosting the visual tree in a Window. This ensures that the WPF layout system correctly applies the SharedSizeGroup properties before you render the visual.
Here’s the corrected code:
Private Sub RenderPageContent(container As ContainerVisual, originalPage As DocumentPage)
    ' Create a temporary window or UserControl to host the visual
    Dim tempWindow As New Window()
    tempWindow.Content = originalPage.Visual ' Assuming Visual is a FrameworkElement like Grid
    tempWindow.Width = originalPage.Size.Width
    tempWindow.Height = originalPage.Size.Height

    ' Force layout update
    tempWindow.UpdateLayout()

    ' Render the Visual to a DrawingVisual
    Dim pageVisual As New DrawingVisual()
    Using ctx As DrawingContext = pageVisual.RenderOpen()
        ctx.DrawRectangle(New VisualBrush(originalPage.Visual), Nothing, New Rect(New Point(), originalPage.Size))
    End Using

    ' Add the rendered visual to the container
    container.Children.Add(pageVisual)

    ' Clean up
    tempWindow.Close()
End Sub

This approach ensures that SharedSizeGroup columns are rendered correctly, resolving the layout issues you were experiencing during off-screen rendering.
